# Nestjsx/crud api not working properly on existing tables

Tags: sql-server, api, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I build my Nextjs project with nestjsx to create Restful api.
My customer.controller.ts

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Crud, CrudController } from '@nestjsx/crud';

import { CustomersService } from './customers.service';
import { Customer } from './entities/customer.entity';

@Crud({
  model: {
    type: Customer,
  },
})
@ApiTags('Customer')
@Controller('customers')
export class CustomersController implements CrudController<Customer> {
  constructor(public service: CustomersService) {}
}
```

my customer.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { TypeOrmCrudService } from '@nestjsx/crud-typeorm';

import { Customer } from './entities/customer.entity';

@Injectable()
export class CustomersService extends TypeOrmCrudService<Customer> {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Customer) repo) {
    super(repo);
  }
}
```

my customers.controller.ts

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Crud, CrudController } from '@nestjsx/crud';

import { CustomersService } from './customers.service';
import { Customer } from './entities/customer.entity';

@Crud({
  model: {
    type: Customer,
  },
})
@ApiTags('Customer')
@Controller('customers')
export class CustomersController implements CrudController<Customer> {
  constructor(public service: CustomersService) {}
}
```

customer.entity.ts

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity('tbl_Customers')
export class Customer {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'int' })
  CustomerID!: number;

  @Column({ type: 'nvarchar', length: 50 })
  CustomerName!: string;

  @Column({ type: 'nvarchar', length: 50 })
  BillingAddressLine1!: string;

  @Column({ type: 'nvarchar', length: 50 })
  BillingAddressLine2: string | null = null;

  @Column({ type: 'nvarchar', length: 50 })
  City!: string;

  @Column({ type: 'nvarchar', length: 8 })
  PostalCode!: string;
}
```

Only Get /customers working, other api endpoints will return `Error: Invalid column name 'undefined'.` I follow every step from the nestjsx doc to setup but cannot find the bug. I also tried setup dto to replace entity in the controller setting, but get the same error. My project connects to mssql and the conection is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching, the solution is to add

```
params: {
    CustomerId: {
      field: 'CustomerID',
      type: 'number',
      primary: true,
    },
  },
```

in the controller as primary key is not default id.